# Difference between vi, vim and macvim

Tags: vim, vi, macvim

Could anyone help me in strongly understanding in detail between these three things vi, vim, and macvim. I read a lot on these 3 things separately, but i couldn't got an overview on all these. I need detail understanding on these 3 things on this topics

1) basic 
2) used for
3) importance in using

Answer (score 7):

- `vi` is the old unix editor that `vim`  is based on. It has a lot of the same concepts as vim but a lot fewer features.
- `vim` is a reimplementation of `vi` by Bram Moolenaar, and is what practically everybody nowadays means when they say `vi`. On many systems, `vi` is symlinked to `vim`.
- `MacVim` is a port of `vim` to OS X including a GUI version (`vim` ships with a gtk-based GUI version that doesn't run natively in OS X)

Answer (score 2):

- **vi**

  - **vi** is a text editor and **vi** was written by Bill Joy in 1976. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi
  - **vi** had not been maintained. You may not need to know about **vi**.
- **Vim**

  - **Vim** is a text editor and **Vim** is based on the idea of the **vi** editor. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)
  - **Vim** has been and will continue to be developed and maintained well by Bram Moolenaar and Vim community.
  - **Vim** is some sort of de facto or one of the most famous text editor for Linux console or such kind of environment.
- **MacVim**

  - **MacVim** is a text editor using **Vim**. Yes, **Vim** is a part of **MacVim**. There are two software components in **MacVim**. GUI and **Vim**. The GUI is based on OS X Cocoa Framework. The GUI launches **Vim** process and communicates with the **Vim** process. The GUI renders window, text and etc, and interacts user keyboard input or mouse input.
  - The GUI works well in OS X GUI system.
  - This **Vim** is actually **Vim**, so you can launch **Vim** directly on Terminal.app from **MacVim.app**.
  - **MacVim** has been and will continue to be developed and maintained well by Björn Winckler and MacVim community.